# How many human beings are/were there?

Tags: humans, population

How many human beings are/were there?

I'm spinning a story where a guy is chosen to represent the whole of humanity. In this story the minds of people who die are preserved in a cool sword that chooses to communicate with a single person every millennium or so. This enables the guy to glean info from any person that lives or has ever lived.

At some point in the story the guy complains that "I'm in charge of the survival of X billion people." I'd like to have some valid number there.

In short: **How many human beings are there?** That's an easy one (got some articles in Google), but on top of that, **how many humans have died in the history of humanity?**

I'd love to have an estimate in the millions, but would be grateful for a billions' estimate.

Comment: 100 - 110 Billion.

Comment: Given that roughly 360000 humans are born every day (according to a quick google search), any correct number down to millions would be obsolete by the time you publish your story.

Comment: Define "human"...

Comment: If you count humans who died as a fetus, baby or infant, your number will easily be 2-3 times as high. So you'll have to draw a line about when a human mind is developed enough for the sword.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986)...

Comment: @Guran  Would be fun to have the character use this line multiple times and slowly increase based on this number.

Comment: As you say, the first question is an easy one, so why do you think it will only be millions?

Comment: @OrangeDog I'd assume OP meant precise down to the millions

Comment: @nzaman: Neil Armstrong and his 100 Billion closest relatives (living or dead).

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Is Australopithecus human? Homo Erectus?

Comment: @nzaman: There's no easy way to make that distinction, which is why the simplest way is saying 'Neil Armstrong and his 100 billion closest relatives.' Nice round number, no fuss, no muss. Sure, at the edge there will be questionable cases, but since a 'species of animal' isn't actually a thing that is, that's going to happen anyway, so might as well have a round number.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: It was the first question I thought of, but later: what of stillbirths/infant deaths; casualties of war/disease that didn't live to see puberty; as KWeiss pointed out, foetuses that didn't make it; do those count?

Comment: @nzaman: All good questions. I guess I would probably say everyone who makes it to the fifth spring equinox (in accordance with their hemisphere of birth) after the first full moon after they were born. It's a weirdly specific definition, I know, but it's fairly unambiguous, and four- or five-year olds are definitely 'people' in the sense that they have motives and thoughts and language and so on. (In the general case, anyway.) Puberty is another good line, but it has the problem of tying participation to breeding, even implicitly.

Comment: As long as you're specific :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43881/discussion-between-williham-totland-and-nzaman).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

107 Billion according to the Population Reference Bureau. [Details Here](http://www.prb.org/Publications/Articles/2002/HowManyPeopleHaveEverLivedonEarth.aspx)

Must warn that this can only be guessed and is based on arbitrary definitions of human.

What we call hominids (i.e., humans) go back further than the supposed 50,000 BCE, but you can do a rough estimate of 600,000,000 max at any point (the maximum capacity of Earth to handle Hunter Gatherers it is assumed) before around 10,000 BCE, with an average life span of 60 years (adults...double the number for children). This means roughly 50 years between complete replacement so we can just calc 600m x 4 (accounting for the full replacement and children that died) for every hundred years.
2.4b/century at 2 to 50 million years would be 240,000,000,000,000/million years so 480 trillion to 12 quadrillion, half of which would be 15 or under and 80% of those 5 or under. More than 99% of all of them being very primitive pre-historic people.

106 billion is the upper limit of "Civilized humans"
50 billion is around the upper limit of "humans lived post-Greek world"
34 billion that lived during and after the crusades
10 billion that have lived in the last 100 years and you could relate to

Comment: Are your numbers just for Homo Sapians, or are we unable to determine how many Homo Sapians alone have ever existed?

Comment: 600m (If I recall correctly) is the estimate for how many hunter gatherers are sustainable on Earth. Home Sapiens haven't been on Earth alone for the majority of that time so only a fraction of that would be Homo Sapien. Also I may have got the 50m year wrong. Not sure. didn't fact check. But it's an arbitrary line so you have to explain that anyways. You could say they link to everyone from x generations back and then forward and you can give a number in line with the numbers in that link.

Comment: Cheers. I see that this article was found by two people while my own googling skills got me nothing..

Answer (score 11):

[According to this article](http://www.prb.org/Publications/Articles/2002/HowManyPeopleHaveEverLivedonEarth.aspx) - How Many People Have Ever Lived On Earth? 108 Billion

```
Year        Population  Births per 1,000    Births Between Benchmarks
50,000 B.C. 2               -               -
8000 B.C.   5,000,000       80              1,137,789,769
1 A.D.      300,000,000     80              46,025,332,354
1200        450,000,000     60              26,591,343,000
1650        500,000,000     60              12,782,002,453
1750        795,000,000     50              3,171,931,513
1850        1,265,000,000   40              4,046,240,009
1900        1,656,000,000   40              2,900,237,856
1950        2,516,000,000   31-38           3,390,198,215
1995        5,760,000,000   31              5,427,305,000
2011        6,987,000,000   23              2,130,327,622


NUMBER WHO HAVE EVER BEEN BORN                    107,602,707,791
World population in mid-2011                        6,987,000,000
Percent of those ever born who are living in 2011   6.5
```

Comment: Why did you post an answer providing the exact same information from the exact same source as Durakken, but three hours later?

Comment: It wasn't until you posted this comment that I realized that our sources were the same. :(

Comment: A population of 2... Sounds a little biblical.

Comment: @UIDAlexD Evolution dictates that in the beginning, there was 0, and then a baby was born or an egg was laid, and that became number 1. In that way, all species start off biblically.

Comment: @Ryan Evolution states that reproductive isolated populations will incur genetic drift until viable offspring become increasingly less likely if not impossible between the isolated populations. There's no point where you can draw a line and say "This is species X, which has just now given birth to species Y with this individual." There's never just one member of a species, because if there was that species would be extinct in a generation.

Comment: @UIDAlexD Yes, you cant draw an exact line, but there is a line. Its not a your child is Sterile because its so different line. Its a line where modern homo sapiens can no longer breed with their ancestors because of the genetic differences, enough to say that the 2 were not the same species. Back then, both those that we could and can not breed with could still breed with eachother, But if we were there, we could only breed with specific individuals.

Comment: @Ryan True, but that line is always moving, and it's a blurry one because - as you said - there won't be a sharp drop in fertility. Saying that a species dates back to a certain era is at best an accounting trick to cope with infinite regress, not a reflection of reality.